# Visual studio c++ typedef vector error

Tags: string, visual-studio, visual-c++, vector, typedef

I am trying to define a vector of string in Visual C++ 2005 like this:

```
void main()
{    
   typedef vector<std::string> temp;
```

But, I am getting an error:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed
```

I have included string.h

What could be the reason?
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Did you included vector too? Why are you using `std::` for `string` but not for `vector`? I would expect `std::vector` too.

Comment: i have included vector.
i have declared using namespace std. so, it does not matter whether i use std:: or not.

Comment: If you are `using namespace std;` you have to say `typedef vector<string> temp;` or say `typedef vector<::std::string> temp;` because within the namespace std there can also be a sub-namespace with the name `std`.

Comment: thanks! I got it to work.
btw, typedef can be inside function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are `using namespace std;` you have to say `typedef vector<string> temp;` or say `typedef vector<::std::string> temp;` because within the namespace std there can also be a sub-namespace with the name std.